# How to confirm if pathname exists?

Tags: bash, symlink, test

How do I test whether a pathname exists?

Previously I was using:

```
realpath -e /some/path
```

Which works except if `/some/path` is a broken symlink, in which case it reports that it does not exist.

```
[ -e /some/path ]
```

Produces a similar outcome to `realpath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check whether `/some/path` exists, either as something that can be completely resolved, or as a broken symbolic link:

```
if [ -e /some/path ] || [ -h /some/path ]; then
    echo '/some/path exists, possibly as a broken symbolic link'
fi
```

The `-h` test is true for a symbolic link, no matter if it's broken or not. There is also a `-L` test which is identical to the `-h` test (historical reasons).

The `-e` tests fails if the given pathname, with all its symbolic links resolved, can not be found. This is why we may have to use `-h` in a separate test if we expect that the filename component of our pathname is a broken symbolic link.